# Tomcat requested resource not available error even though file present

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I have a dashboard that is hosted on an apache tomcat server on a centos machine. I kept the files that needed to be downloaded onclick in the following path

```
project_name/resources/filename
```

So onclick, I had the `href` set to the above path, and the browser used to download the file (I am talking about `.xlsm` file here). But for some weird reason, now the file doesn't download at all. I am getting a `The requested resource is not available.` error. I am sure that the file is there. I added a pdf and a pptx file in the same folder and tried to access it directly using their respective url, but I am getting the same error.

But if it is a file that the browser can display, for example, a txt file or a json file, I can view it on the browser by directly accessing it.

Since earlier the file used to get downloaded, I am guessing some settings might have changed. What do I need to do to rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the permission of the file in `webapps/project_name/resources/filename` to `rwxrwxrwx`. This has solved the issue for me.